# Match colors between two digital photos, given corresponding camera settings?

Tags: computer-vision

I am learning about photo calibration.

Assume I toke two photo of a static scene in exactly same position, using the same camera, same lens, same focal length... So nothing is changed geometrically.

The only things changed are the exposure time, bias, white balance and maybe gain, and those settings that affect the pixel colors. I need a formula that maps from photo 1 to photo 2.

in code it would be like:

`photo2_est = magicFunction(photo1, settings_of_camera1, settings_of_camera2)`

What exactly are the involved settings and how should I map the colors?

Any good resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are talking of a "transfer function", which is commercially implemented as a "look-up table" (LUT).

a transfer function operates on individual pixels and maps them to new luma and chroma values.

you also need to know about gamma mapping. you need to work in a linear space for equations/formulas to make sense. RGB values are typically gamma-mapped. unmap them to manipulate them, remap them for display or storage.

- exposure time and gain would be just factors, in a linear color space.
- bias would be addition.
- white balance is also multiplication, but with different factors for R/G/B or the luma+chroma channels.